# Flutter background color with degree

Tags: flutter, dart

I am practicing flutter web by replicating the templates. I am stuck at drawing this degree background with white and green separation.

How can I achieve it?

[image]

Edit:
My code snippet & result so far

```
Widget body(context) {
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Colors.white,
          Color(0xff00a78e),
          Color(0xff00a78e),
        ],
        stops: [0, 0.5, 0.5],
        begin: Alignment(0, -1),
        end: Alignment(1, 1),
      ),
      .....
      .....
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a code snippet what you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a custome clipper, this sample code might be a good start for you:

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        ClipPath(
          clipper: CustomeShape(),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5),
                  child: Text(
                    'Testing clipping with soft wrap',
                    softWrap: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )


class CustomeShape extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width * 2 / 3, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomeShape oldClipper) => false;
}
```

the output would look something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you. You show me this advanced tip.